# Laravel 5.6 Unit Test Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I have a Laravel project running version 5.6. 
The connected database is mongodb with the jenssegers/mongodb package.

I wrote a single Unittest to test a function related to the User.

The test creates new users in a configured test mongodb database.
I want to refresh the database after each test run so I use the `RefreshDatabase` Trait.

When using the `RefreshDatabase` Trait I get the following error when running my test:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Tests\Unit\UserTest::it_gets_top_user
>       Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

When not using the Trait the test creates all the necessary stuff in the database and performs the assertion without an error.

The test looks like this:

```
/** @test */
public function it_gets_top_user()
{
    factory(\App\Users\User::class, 5)->create();

    $userOne = factory(\App\Users\User::class)->create([
        'growth' => 10
    ]);

    $topUser = Users::getTopUser();

    $collection = new Collection();

    $collection->push($userOne);


    $this->assertEquals($collection, $topUser);
}
```

I use the following versions in my composer.json:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
"jenssegers/mongodb": "3.4.*",
"phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
```

The following versions are used on the server:

- PHP 7.2
- MongoDB 3.4
- PHP MongoDB Extension 1.4.2

I call the test with the phpunit installed in the vendor directory with:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: `it_gets_top_ten_users` or `it_gets_top_user` ??

Comment: @kerbholz this was a copy and paste fail. It is `it_gets_top_user`.

Comment: Did you try changing the configuration in `config/queue.php`?

Comment: @shalvah I followed the documentation of the jenssegers/mongodb package and configured the `config/queue.php` as described there. No success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that the `RefreshDatabase` Trait does not work at all for a MongoDB environment.

I solved the above problem by creating my own `RefreshDatabase` Trait in the `testing/` directory of my Laravel project.

The Trait looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

trait RefreshDatabase
{
    /**
     * Define hooks to migrate the database before and after each test.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function refreshDatabase()
    {
        $this->dropAllCollections();
    }

    /**
     * Drop all collections of the testing database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function dropAllCollections()
    {
        $database = $this->app->make('db');

        $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () use ($database) {
            // list all collections here
            $database->dropCollection('users');
        });
    }
}
```

To enable this Trait I have overridden the `setUpTraits` function in the `TestCase` Class. It now looks like this:

```
/**
 * Boot the testing helper traits.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function setUpTraits()
{
    $uses = array_flip(class_uses_recursive(static::class));

    if (isset($uses[\Tests\RefreshDatabase::class])) {
        $this->refreshDatabase();
    }

    if (isset($uses[DatabaseMigrations::class])) {
        $this->runDatabaseMigrations();
    }

    if (isset($uses[DatabaseTransactions::class])) {
        $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
    }

    if (isset($uses[WithoutMiddleware::class])) {
        $this->disableMiddlewareForAllTests();
    }

    if (isset($uses[WithoutEvents::class])) {
        $this->disableEventsForAllTests();
    }

    if (isset($uses[WithFaker::class])) {
        $this->setUpFaker();
    }

    return $uses;
}
```

And finally in all my testing classes I can use my newly created Trait like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Tests\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    // tests happen here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An improvement would be to avoid copy/pasting Laravel's `setUpTraits()` method by simply calling `$uses = parent::setUpTraits();` and then just add the `if` that checks for the custom trait. Also to avoid "listing all collections" manually, you could iterate `foreach ($database->listCollections() as $coll)` and then call `$database->dropCollection($coll->getName());`.